# Python & OpenCV : Assertion Failed with IP Camera in Exe File

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build a simple code to test my cameras. In my code, I use these lines for webcam;

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("test")
ret, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imshow("test", frame)
```

and for IP camera

```
myip='http://admin:wicaledon@XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX/stream/video/mjpeg'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(str(myip))
cv2.namedWindow("test")
ret, frame = cam.read()
cv2.imshow("test", frame)
```

**In PyCharm, when I run both codes,** my cameras works perfectly. Also if I enter `myip` url in browser, ip camera shows perfectly.

**But, when I build an exe file with PyInstaller** , only the first code (webcam code) works. The second code shows this error;

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'`

Where is my fault? Can you fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your problem is connected to [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2950). There is a workaround suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2950#issuecomment-455891842). It suggests to run pyinstaller as

`pyinstaller -F --add-data opencv_ffmpeg410_64.dll;. script.py`

I've adapted it to your OpenCV version. Make sure this dll exists anywhere.